# Show/hide a certain number of Excel rows based on cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm creating a loan repayment calculator schedule with Excel 2010, where the user inputs loan amount, interest rate and duration (in months), and the calculator returns the repayment value for each month. I would like the calculator to show/hide rows based on the duration of the loan (es. 12 months=show 12 rows). Is this possible?

[image: spreadsheet]

[Link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A49066AB95664D8D!377&authkey=!AKV-aCwBQN7H3KE&ithint=file%2Cxlsx) to the sheet.

Comment: you can't show / hide rows with worksheetfunctions, but can set cells to be empty certain criteria met. Please share more details on your work to help us support you with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm estimating from your linked spreadsheet that the duration is in cell A10 and that the output table is in columns C through F with the column headings in row 1.  So `ROW()-1` gives you the month number.

For the month column, C2 would be:

```
=IF(ROW()-1>$A$10,"",ROW()-1)
```

Copy that down for the maximum number of months you will ever need.  Rows beyond the duration months will be filled with blank.  Otherwise, it will display the month number.

I won't get into your formulas in columns D through F, but D and E would be similar:

```
=IF(ROW()-1>$A$10,"",your_formula)
```

Column F is slightly trickier because you want a sum.  You could do that with:

```
=IF(ROW()-2=$A$10,SUM(F$2:INDIRECT("F"&$A$10+1)),IF(ROW()-1>$A$10,"",your_formula))
```

This tests to see if it is the summation row, in which case it calculates the range to use and the sum.  Otherwise, it treats the cells similar to the other columns.