# How can this VBA be adjusted

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

As per your request The original post is here [How do I hide rows based on a cell value](https://superuser.com/questions/1407077/how-do-i-hide-rows-based-on-a-cell-value)

I have received the VBA below from Ted D, following a question I posted here. 
Unfortunately it is not working completely:

•   After I insert the first number (but not 0) in a cell in B column, all the rows that have zero in that column are hidden - which is great.

•   The problem is - and please excuse me for not mentioning it from the beginning- that everytime I use that worksheet, several cells in B column must be filled with numbers bigger than 0. So, it would be of much help to hide the rows that contain 0 in column B, after I filled all the other cells that I need.

•   I was thinking, that maybe, if there is a condition - the rows with 0 in B column to be hidden  only after a certain  merged cell is filled with text? I do not know if it is possible, but I have no other idea.

This is the VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

  ' Hide Rows if row value in watch_Column is hide_On_Value.
  ' watch_Column must include start_on row number (e.g. A1 or C3)

  ' Hidden rows, beyond the range of cells with values, may not
  ' unhide. For speed, only process rows being used <= end_of_watch.
    Const watchColumn = "B45" ' Beginning Cell (row and column) to watch.
    Const endOfWatch = "135" ' Last row. if "", rest of rows in use.
    Const hideOnValue = 0

    Dim hideRange As Range
    Dim unhideRange As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim seeRow As Boolean
    Dim watchStart() As String
    Dim lastRow As String
    Dim tmpEnableEvents As Boolean

    Set watchRange = Me.UsedRange ' call and discard to reset LastCell
    lastRow = Me.Range(watchColumn).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    If endOfWatch <> "" Then
       If Val(lastRow) > Val(endOfWatch) Then lastRow = endOfWatch
    End If
    watchStart = Split(Me.Range(watchColumn).Address(True, False), "$")
    If Val(watchStart(1)) > Val(lastRow) Then Exit Sub
    tmpEnableEvents = Application.EnableEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each r In Me.Range(watchColumn & ":" & watchStart(0) & lastRow)
        seeRow = True
        If IsEmpty(r) Then
        ElseIf CStr(r.Value2) = vbNullString Then
        ElseIf r = hideOnValue Then
            seeRow = False
            If Not r.EntireRow.Hidden Then
                If hideRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set hideRange = r
                Else
                    Set hideRange = Union(hideRange, r)
                End If
            End If
        End If
        If seeRow And r.EntireRow.Hidden Then
            If unhideRange Is Nothing Then
                Set unhideRange = r
            Else
                Set unhideRange = Union(unhideRange, r)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    If Not unhideRange Is Nothing Then
        unhideRange.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Not hideRange Is Nothing Then
        hideRange.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = tmpEnableEvents
End Sub
```

Thank you very much for your help!

**The initial situation was:**

I have a worksheet which has many formulas and I need the following to happen: when this worksheet is used, and some cells on different rows are filled with a number other than 0, the rows which contain cells with 0, to hide automatically. And this should happen every time that worksheet is used, with different values. 
About the attached example:

•   The value that changes is in column B

•   D, E and F are merged cells on each row

• [image] talking about the attached example: I need rows with Text2, Text 4 and Text 5 to be hidden automatically, because in B column the value is zero for these rows.

IMPORTANT! - at each use of the worksheet, the rows that have 0 in column B are different. Not always the same. And also, this automatization must apply only to a certain selection in the document (let's say from rows 45 to 135).

Comment: Could you Share the link of the original question @TED D. responded, help us to understand the real need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I hide rows based on a cell value](https://superuser.com/questions/1407077/how-do-i-hide-rows-based-on-a-cell-value)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would've been better just to ask Ted make changes by commenting on his answer.

There are several ways of going at this, you just have to decide on how you want it to work.

You could have the document hide rows when the number `0`is entered:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo ProcError
If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value = "0" Then
        Target.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End If
ProcError:
End Sub
```

You could use a button, to manually run a macro of hiding all the rows.
(example code on generic loop, slower than the original macro)

```
Sub hideZero()
Dim searchMe As Range, zero As Range
Set searchMe = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("B2"), Range("B1048576").End(xlUp))
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each zero In searchMe
    If zero.Value2 = 0 Then
        zero.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next zero
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This is a slow code, and if you have a LOT of rows, excel will freeze for a while.

If you want to go with your suggestion of *"the rows with 0 in B column to be hidden only after a certain merged cell is filled with text?"* you could use the first approach with `Worksheet_Change`, but monitoring that cell instead, and have the event run the macro instead of a button:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim checkMe As Range
Set checkMe = Range("A1") 'Change to Wherever the cell is
On Error GoTo ProcError
If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), checkMe) Is Nothing Then
    If Not Target.Value2 = "" Then
        Call hideZero
    End If
End If
ProcError:
End Sub
```

Although this can be quite a surprise for the end user, having  macros started without warning. So you should probably put a warning there. You could do that by changing the `If` calling the sub to:

```
If Not Target.Value2 = "" Then
    msgboxResult = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to continue?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Warning!")
    If msgboxResult = vbYes Then Call hideZero
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired behavior can be obtained with these one time edits:

- Change the Sub name from `Worksheet_Calculate` to `Hide_Rows`.
- Change the Sub scope from `Private` to `Public`.
- Save Changes.

To update the hidden rows:

- Make Edits to the Worksheet.
- Stay on the hidden rows sheet.
- Hide the rows by opening the Macro dialogue using <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd>.
- Double click (*run*) `<sheetName>!Hide_Rows`.

**N.B.** The original answer used the sheet module specific to the worksheet with the hidden rows. To make running the macro available when this is not the active sheet, the Sub (macro) will need to be moved to a general module. In this case, additional edits to the Sub `Hide_Rows` should be made so the active sheet is not acted on but instead the specific worksheet with the hidden rows is filtered.